# Is this left recursion in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm using swipl 5.10.2. I started today learning Prolog for my AI course.
I've started with a pretty straight forward example:

```
father(giovanni,maria).
brother(paolo,pietro).

grandpa(X,Y) :-
        father(X,Z),
        father(Z,Y).
grandpa(X,Y) :-
        father(X,Z),
        mother(Z,Y).

mother(maria,paolo).
mother(I,J) :-
        mother(I,K),
        brother(K,J).
```

Not a big deal, if I try this goal `grandpa(giovanni,pietro)`, it work and it gives me **true**. Then I want to spicy up the challenge and I modified the code like this:

```
father(giovanni,maria).
brother(paolo,pietro).

grandpa(X,Y,Z) :-
        father(X,Z),
        father(Z,Y).
grandpa(X,Y,Z) :-
        father(X,Z),
        mother(Z,Y).

mother(maria,paolo).
mother(I,J) :-
        mother(I,K),
        brother(K,J).
```

because I wanted to know the *middle-man* but when I run it here's what happens:

```
?- grandpa(giovanni,pietro,M).
M = maria ;
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

That's because, imho, there's a left recursion in mother, the tree keeps expanding without finding closure.

Then I wrote this:

```
father(giovanni,maria).
brother(paolo,pietro).
mother(maria,paolo).

grandpa(X,Y,Z) :-
        father(X,Z),
        father(Z,Y).
grandpa(X,Y,Z) :-
        father(X,Z),
        mother(Z,Y).

mother(I,J) :-
        brother(K,J),
        mother(I,K).
```

This is the output:

```
?- grandpa(giovanni,pietro,M).
M = maria ;
false.
```

It is right. So is it just a left recursion problem or am I missing something about swipl behaviour? And when I have a *"ERROR: Out of local stack"*, is it always a recursion problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the `Out of local stack` error is almost always (or always) from recursions that are too deep; in simple programs, those recursions are likely to be infinite.  The problem in your code is indeed the left recursion issue; trying to solve `mother(anything, B)` will try to solve `mother(anything, B1)`, `mother(anything, B2)`, and so on until you run out of stack space.

Comment: +1 and I want to add that the maximum recursion depth varies considerably depending upon the number and sizes of the terms that are handled (easily by factor 100 by factor 100 if lists are involved) and that *tail recursion* is the solution to largely circumventing excessive stack use.

Comment: if *tail recursion* is supported by the compiler though. Like you can do it in Java but the JVM does not support it, right?

Comment: This code does not have that problem, though; it is an infinite recursion, independently of whether tail calls are used or not (in this case, reordering the goals in the rule for `mother` would fix the problem).